# Additive commutators and the center of a division ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, division-algebras

Can someone please explain me the following proof?

Proposition: If $D$ is a division ring, then the division ring $R$ generated by $Z(D)$ and all additive commutators (elements of the form $xy-yx$) is the whole of $D$.

Proof: Let $x$ be a member of $Z(D)$. Then there exists $y$ in $D$, such that $xy\neq yx$, therefore $x(xy - yx)$ is in $R^*$, and $xy - yx$ is in $R^*$, thus $x$ is in $R^*$.

Thanks!
G.

Comment: Maybe you want to say $x\notin Z(D)$.

Comment: even if x is not in Z(D), I still don't understand the proof

Comment: what is [x,xy]?
anyway, the way I look at it, we need to take an element of R, and show it is an element of D. I don't see where is it done here.

Comment: yep, the converse. just confused, sorry. so any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in D$. If $x\in Z(D)$, then $x\in R$. If $x\notin Z(D)$ then there is $y\in D$ such that $xy\neq yx$. But $xy-yx\in R^*$ and $x(xy-yx)=x(xy)-(xy)x\in R^*$, so $x\in R$.

Comment: how do we know that xy-yx is invertible in R?

Comment: you are correct, I said that R is a division ring. Thanks you for your help. my problem is a bit different, the following: show that as a Z(D) algebra, D is generated by the commutators